# Будет ли в данном случае повторное копирование объекта на стеке?

Tags: c++

Будет ли в данном случае повторное копирование объекта на стеке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
auto const appInfo = vk::ApplicationInfo()
    .setPApplicationName(appName)
    .setApiVersion(apiVersion)
    .setApplicationVersion(VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0));
```

И вот так

```
auto appInfo = vk::ApplicationInfo()
    .setPApplicationName(appName)
    .setApiVersion(apiVersion)
    .setApplicationVersion(VK_MAKE_VERSION(1, 0, 0));
```

Comment: А какой тип возвращает `.setPApplicationName`?

Comment: Будет возвращено в результате функции vk::ApplicationInfo&

Comment: Хм. Для const по идее не должно быть, а вот для не-const не уверен.

Comment: Неплохой вопрос, почему минус? Вопрос про привязку временного объекта.

Comment: Ну вот я потестил вызывается копирование, если не const. Что стандарт говорит?

Comment: Но вы бы положили информацию о возвращаемых типах в вопрос, а то так неясно.

Comment: Честно говоря, мне не верится, что без const код правильный. У вас же по сути присваивается ссылка на временный объект.

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: Код без const от Lunar я его подправил.

Comment: Хотя стоп, тип `appInfo` — не `ApplicationInfo&`, а `ApplicationInfo`. Пусть придут наши гуру C++.

Comment: Intellisense говорит, что будет ApplicationInfo хотя возвращается ссылка .

Comment: Угу, но вопрос не в том, что возвращает функция, а в том, во что раскрывается `auto`.

Comment: С++ 14 дожна быть ссылка. Ну если так возникает следующий вопрос отработает, как просто инициализации структуры или будет вызываться копирование

Comment: модификатор const тут не играет роли - ,обьект будет копироватся

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Вы правы только что проверил в данно случае надо использовать auto const& object = Object().setX().setY();

Comment: вопрос в том какой обьект, потому что  наверное setApplicationVersion() возвращает старую версию и устанавливает новую

Comment: @ARHovsepyan set возаращает ссылку на объект там все норм.

Comment: ну  я так и предпологал